# Zend framework findManyToManyRowset with condition on 3rd column

Tags: php, zend-framework, many-to-many

Is there a way I can do a condition on the join table with a many to many in ZF ?

For example I have table A | A_B |B

And B has columns A_ID | B_ID | PUBLISHED

```
$model = new Model_DbTable_A();
$select = $model->select()->where('id = ?', $id);
$row = $model->fetchRow($select);
$b = $row->findManyToManyRowset('Model_DbTable_B', 'Model_DbTable_AB');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a `Zend_Db_Table_Select` object as the fifth parameter to `findManyToManyRowset()`. In the final select statement, intersection table is aliased as `i`. So you can set a condition on the intersection table in such a way:

```
$select = $this->select()
               ->where( 'i.published = ?', true );
$b = $row->findManyToManyRowset(
               'Model_DbTable_B', 'Model_DbTable_AB', 
               $callerRefRule, $matchRefRule, 
               $select);
```

The apparent downside of this approach is that it's relying on `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract` internals too much and, therefore, does not look clear unless peeking into `findManyToManyRowset()` definition.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this (this is slight modification of the answer by Vika):

```
$model = new Model_DbTable_A();
$row = $model->find($id)->current(); // lite shortcut to get $row by $id

// get select object
$select = $model->select()->where('i.published = ?', true);

// fetch rows in B through A_B table where A_B.published is true
$b = $row->findManyToManyRowset('Model_DbTable_B', 'Model_DbTable_AB', null, null, $select);
```

Comment: Just in what exact way is it different? Except that omitting the name of the reference rules may be harmful in case there's more than one rule.

Comment: @Vika. In your version you used $this->select() and it is not clear what $this refers to. Omitting rules is not harmful if you know what you are doing. Specifically, "if you don't specify a rule, the method uses the first rule in the $_referenceMap array that matches the tables in the relationship".

Comment: Regarding `$this->select()` you're right, my bad, I was assuming this code goes into a class extending `Zend_Db_Table_Row` or `Zend_Db_Table`. Sure, if this code's a part of a controller, `$this->select()` is not defined. Hopefully, no one is ever going to put this code into a controller ;)